# How to make sure a chapter starts on an odd numbered page in CSS when printing HTML?

Tags: html, css, printing

In the past, when I have made printable books or PDFs, I was able to calculate exactly how many "lines" were on a page, because I was making a dictionary where every entry fit on one line. Then I just calculated how many lines could fit on a page, and when I wanted to create a new chapter header starting on an odd page, I would just insert an empty page in the list of pages in HTML (when generating the HTML from the content).

However, now I have dynamic free-form text, and I am not sure how many pages it will end up being, and I want it to be dynamic so if content is added/subtracted it will always automatically put any new chapter starting on an odd numbered page (the right side when looking at a book). If the content ends on an odd page, then it should insert an extra blank page somehow (on the left, the back of the odd page), so the new chapter again starts on the next odd page (on the right). Can it be done somehow using CSS or, if not, other techniques?